# Notation for the assumed probabilistic model of our data

Tags: probability, notation

The question of best practices for probability notation is a common one on this forum, e.g.[here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/124901/gibbs-sampling-and-probability-notation), [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/279245/probability-notation-in-logistic-regression), [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/172735/notation-related-to-probability-spaces), and elsewhere, e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1069089/notation-abuse-for-random-variables-distributions-pdfs-pmfs), [here](https://lingpipe-blog.com/2009/10/13/whats-wrong-with-probability-notation/), [here](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DwCAkVlXQAAMF25.jpg). Despite this, I still have unresolved questions.

As an example, if I have a coin whose probability of coming up Heads is $\theta$, then I would normally say that the outcome of the coin toss is modelled as a binary random variable $X$ whose probability distribution is a Bernoulli distribution with parameter $\theta$, or 
$$
X \sim \text{Bernoulli}(\theta).
$$

My first question is whether or not, even if everyone knows what I mean, this is sloppy notation and I can and should be more precise in either or both my notation or terminology?

A related question is, if I observed $n$ repetitions of coin toss above, I would normally write
$$
X_i \sim \text{Bernoulli}(\theta), \quad{\text{for $i \in 1...n$}}.
$$
By this, I take it that I am saying that I have $n$ independent random variables, each with one observation. Should I instead be saying that there is actually just one random variable, i.e. $X$, but $n$ independent observations of it? In other words, in a situation like this, is it better to say that we have 1 random variable, or $n$ iid random variables?